# How to check if list has at least one element without looping

Tags: java, collections

My question is quite clear.

I have a list and I want to be sure that it has at least one not null element. And that too, without looping (performance measurement).

```
list.size()
```

is definitely not helpful here. Because if the list contains 5 null values, then also its size will be 5.

Please note that, I'm not asking for a list that cannot contain `null`.

Comment: It's redundant to add "in Java" when it's tagged.

Comment: FWIW, old question I know, but this can be done with Java 8 without loops (using streams). That said, if performance is the goal here, then that won't really help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to do this with the standard `List` implementations without looping,  either explicitly or implicitly<sup>1</sup>.  This is not supported by the `List` API, and none of the standard list classes included as a specialized operation.

The only way to avoid looping is to create a custom `List` implementation that treats `null` as special, and keeps a count of the number of `null` elements in the list.  And the downside of that approach is that update operations on the list are more expensive because they need to test to see if the counter needs to be changed.

Note that using a hand-coded loop is typically not that expensive because you can stop looping as soon as you see a non-null element.

---

<sup>1 - If you are concerned about efficiency, then an implicit loop in some method like `Collections.frequency` is likely to be much more expensive than a loop that is hand-code expressly for this purpose.</sup>

---

**FOLLOW-UP**

> I'm not creating or filling the list. I got the already generated list from some code that I cannot alter.

In that case, a loop like the following is the fastest possible solution:

```
boolean empty = true;
for (SomeType t : list) {
   if (t != null) {
       empty = false;
       break;
   }
}
```

Indexing *might* be marginally faster if the list is an `ArrayList`, but not for a `LinkedList`.

Comment: Hard coding it is still Worst case and average case O(n). Just a constant factor of 1/2 on average.

Comment: @Cruncher - There are better measures of actual performance than Big O complexity.

Comment: @StephenC thanks for the answer but I'm not creating or filling the list. I got the already generated list from some code that I cannot alter.

Comment: My point is that Big O is an indicator of how performance scales, not a measure of performance.  If two algorithms have the same Big O complexity, it doesn't necessarily mean they perform the same.

Comment: @StephenC I know, I was making a joke, because they make such a big deal about complexity. Insertion sort can out perform merge sort, if you know something about the data set.

Comment: @Cruncher - The other flaw in your analysis is that you appear to be assuming that there is only one non-null element in the array ... in your average-case,  There's nothing in the Question to justify that.

Comment: @StephenC Yes, to do a real analysis I need the probability that a given element is null, you're right.

Answer (score 6):

You can create your own implementation of list that keeps the number of non-null elements in a local variable and updates it every time elements are added and removed.

Comment: +1 I was about to suggest this. If the O(1) is really that important

Comment: I too. But its a bit out of context according to the question

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento I'm not sure out of scope is relevant, if it's the only actual answer that doesn't involve looping(or a library that loops).

Comment: It wholly depends on how you must understand *"I have a list"*. I understood that OP already had an object implementing List.

Comment: @Joni thanks for the answer but I'm not creating or filling the list. I got the already generated list from some code that I cannot alter.

Comment: @RAS In that case, dystroy's answer is right. You have no way around looping.

Answer (score 3):

If you receive an object on which you only know it's a list (that is, it implements `List`), you have no other solution that directly or indirectly looping.

The [`List` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) doesn't provide such feature and I know of no commonly available implementation providing it.

You have no other choice than to loop or to call a method which loops.

EDIT : Of course, if you write the list class yourself, you can do what you want like having a counter.

Comment: There's other choices... but I didn't downvote but thought about it for a minute

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Please let aside the opinions and give me a few implementations providing it.

Comment: @Cruncher I may have misunderstood the question. If OP writes the list himself, of course he can do what he wants.

Comment: @Cruncher I don't know nor I think its of widespread use. But you said they have no reason and not that you don't know one that have that implemented. That's a difference between facts and opniation.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento I think you meant to tag dystroy, not me

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Seriously... You know that most implementations don't have this feature, this isn't an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.frequency(list, null) > 0
```

Comment: This loops. And it's more costly than a custom loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if the copy constructor of `ArrayList` is actually looping but this does the trick, using `String` for my example. `removeAll` does loop internally on the other hand... so that's not really "not looping"...

```
  List<String> testLst = new ArrayList<String>();
  testLst.add(null);
  testLst.add(null);
  testLst.add(null);
  testLst.add(null);

  List<String> testLst2 = new ArrayList<String>();
  testLst2.add(null);
  testLst2.add(null);
  testLst2.add(null);
  testLst2.add(null);
  testLst2.add("test");

  List<String> nullLst = new ArrayList<String>();
  nullLst.add(null);
  List<String> removedNull = new ArrayList<String>(testLst);
  removedNull.removeAll(nullLst);

  if (testLst.size() > 0 && removedNull.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println("Contains non-null");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Contains only null or empty");
  }

  removedNull = new ArrayList<String>(testLst2);
  removedNull.removeAll(nullLst);
  if (testLst2.size() > 0 && removedNull.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println("Contains non-null");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Contains only null or empty");
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the wrong question. You cannot tell if a list contains `null` elements without looking at the elements. I could give an answer using recursion, but that would be less performant and just circumvent using any loop statements.

What you want is either a collection that doesn't allow null in the first place or create a class that implements the list interface and keeps track of whether null values are contained in a private field.